# How do I run burp scanner

Tags: burp, security-review

How do I run burp scan? Do I have to buy a burp suite? What is partner license mentioned in [this](https://security.secure.force.com/apex/security_tools_webapp_scanner_request) url?

Answer (score 6):

[Burp](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/) is software that does security scanning on web applications. The goal of the software is to find security vulnerabilities.

Salesforce provides partners a security scan once a year. If you are not a salesforce partner, you could buy the software yourself.

To [qualify](https://security.secure.force.com/apex/security_tools_webapp_scanner_request) as a salesforce partner and use the [Burp Scanner](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/scanner.html) you must:

- Be enrolled in the AppExchange or OEM program, and have a Partner
  Portal login
- Be current with your AppExchange Listing Fees
- Application contains integrations with web-services not residing on
  the Force.com Platform. If your application completely resides on
  Force.com, please use the Force.com Security Source Scanner instead.

Comment: My SFDC App sends request to two urls (both written by me). But they don't have UI and are just api's to a larger application which pulls and pushes data to Salesforce. Do I still need Burp Scanner. Contacting external service this way `<apex:commandButton action="https://sfdc.datadoctorit.com/authenticate?key={!key}" image="{! $Resource.authBtn }"/>`