# Why & How to use Burp Suite for Salesforce External Services

Tags: managed-package, security-review, burp, zap

I am investigating the possibility of using `Burp` as an alternative to [Chimera](https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/) or [OWASP Zap](https://www.zaproxy.org/) to provide a scan report of an External Service in the Salesforce Security Review.

The information that I am finding, either in Salesforce docs or StackExchange post is quite outdated (up to 2014 overall). Some examples are:

- [Burp suite guide by `Cloud Security`](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/webapp/burpabout)
- [Burp suite guide by Daniel Ballinger (2013)](http://www.fishofprey.com/2013/01/using-burp-suite-to-test-web-service.html)
  and things seem to have changed since then.
- Some StackExchange posts such as *[How to run burp](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/how-do-i-run-burp-scanner)*, where at the moment a Burp Suite license was provided if you were going through the Security Review process as a partner. I don't think this license is provided by Salesforce happening anymore.

As a result, all this information is creating more confusion rather than helping, therefore I would appreciate some help to have a clear overview of the `Burp` tool.

There are a few main questions I would love to know before closing my investigation:

1. There are three different Burp products, namely Enterprise Edition, Professional, and Community (the last one is free). [Salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_test_all.htm) only mention using `Burp Suite`, however, **which Burp product should be chosen for creating the scan and why?**
2. Can we confirm that Salesforce does not provide a `Burp license` for the external app security review? The [latest Salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_test_all.htm) contradict answers like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/how-do-i-run-burp-scanner).
3. **Is there any decision-maker between choosing `OWASP Zap` or `Burp Suite` in case that Chimera is not an option?**
4. Can I trust the same guidelines for Burp usage that I referenced at the top?

Comment: We used Burp for a couple of years, paying the subscription fees for it ourselves. We since moved to using Zap since this is free and does what is required by Salesforce; they accept the Zap report as part of our submissions (or at least did up to the last time we needed to go through security review). My recommendation: don't bother with Burp Suite. It's unnecessary since Zap is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilW, I will take it into account. I was wondering if Burp provides any critical findings that Zap doesn't, however, what you say and below answer makes me think that it does not provide anything that Zap wouldn't - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29525/anyone-have-examples-of-genuine-security-issues-identified-by-the-burp-scanner-f?rq=1